# How to compare distances measured in spaces of different dimensionality

Tags: metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, dimensional-analysis

I would like to know if there is any way to compare distances measured in spaces of different dimensionality.
Say we have two points in $\mathbb{R}^N$, two other points in $\mathbb{R}^M$ with $M \neq N$.

How can I say if the two points in $\mathbb{R}^N$ are closer than the two points in $\mathbb{R}^M$?

Taking a particular example, using euclidean distance alone seems "unfair" given that points in higher dimension will tend to have greater distances between them. Maybe that's just the way it is, but I wanted to know if one could somehow normalize for the dimensions or something.

**Edit1: I add this here, it's in the comments, but to make it more visible.**

I have a concrete application:
I am working with Convolutional Neural Networks of varying architectures for image classification. At the end of the convolutional layers, there is a Mx1 (or Nx1, or (the corresponding dimension)x1) vector that in some way is an internal representation of the image for the neural net in a high dimensional space before the final classification.
I want to feed the same images to different architectures and compare the distance in both representations.
For example given an image of a Dog and another of a Cat, what's the distance between "cat" and "dog" in the different spaces generated by the different cnn?
I tried to keep it general in the original question, but that is what I am working on.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: You may want to elaborate on your application.  I suspect what you have in mind is something along the lines of "average pairwise distance in analogous regions of different dimension", e.g. average distance of two points inside unit hypercubes of different dimension.  However, taken at face value, the obvious answer to your question is that given by @uniquesolution, which does not seem to be what your question is getting at.

Answer (score 4):

Suppose $M<N$. Then you can embed $\mathbb{R}^M$ into $\mathbb{R}^N$ and any distance that you measured between points $p,q$ in $\mathbb{R}^M$ will be exactly the same distance you will measure between the the correspondiing embedded points in $\mathbb{R}^N$. More precisely, there is a (natural) isometric embedding $i:\mathbb{R}^M\to\mathbb{R}^N$ such that $d(p,q)=d(i(p),i(q))$ for every $p,q\in \mathbb{R}^M$. (Here $d$ is the Euclidean distance).

Therefore, the points in $\mathbb{R}^M$ are no closer and no farther away that they are in $\mathbb{R}^N$. The statement "points in higher dimension will tend to have greater distances" does not make much sense, because - as you can see, if these are the same points, in the sense that they were embedded into the higher dimensional space from a lower-dimensional one, then their distance is the same, whereas if they are different points, then there is no base of comparison.

Comment: Hi! I believe the answer lies in your last sentence. If the points are indeed different, then it is impossible to make the distance comparable? Having two pair of points, each pair being different of the other, there is no way to compare those distances in a meaningful way, if I understood correctly.

Comment: @nico_so Certainly you can compare distances. Just compare the magnitude of the vector $\vec{AB}=\vec B - \vec A$ with the magnitude of vector $\vec{CD} = \vec D - \vec C$.

Comment: Hi @gandalf61 doesn't that give as a result another vector?

Comment: @nico No. You are comparing the magnitudes of the two vectors, and the magnitudes are scalars.

Comment: @gandalf61 Oh, i did not read the "compare magnitude".
But to get a magnitude we need to define a Norm in each vector space,  are norms in different spaces comparables?

Comment: @nico_so Yes, you just use the same norm (Euclidean metric, for example) in both vector spaces. I suppose you could have a problem if you intentionally equip the two vector spaces with different norms, but that would be a strange and rather pointless thing to do.

Comment: @gandalf61 Ok, thanks. But how does that handle that higher dimensions would have a "tendency to bigger distances". A concrete example is:  suppose we have R³ and R⁴ this adds one more term inside the square-root. As the difference in dimensions gets bigger, you keep adding more and more terms to that sum, and that is why I am not sure if they are really comparable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122388/discussion-between-gandalf61-and-nico-so).

Answer (score 3):

The answer really depends on the use you want to make of this distance comparison.

If your context suggests that you take into account the fact that there are more ways/coordinates of points to differ in high dimensions then the answer from @uniquesolution won't work. You might consider instead letting the distance between two points be the average of the absolute values of the differences of coordinates. That scales the taxicab ($L_1$) metric by the reciprocal of the dimension.

You could  scale any metric - perhaps the Euclidean distance (what you call normalizing  for the dimension) by the reciprocal of the dimension.

Comment: Hi! I have quite a concrete application on what I am doing: I am working with CNN of varying architectures for image classification. At the end, there is a Mx1 (or Nx1) vector representing the output of the CNN, before the final classification happens. I want to feed to different architectures the same image and compare the distance in both representations. For example given an image of a Dog and another of a Cat, what's the distance between "cat" and "dog" in the different spaces? 
Thank you for your ideas, and I hope this also gives some more context.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard way to make the comparison you want. I suggest that you experiment with different ways to do it (I suggested two) and see which work best in your interesting classification problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ... points in higher dimensions will tend to have greater distances between them

This is not true, and I think this is where you have a basic misconception.

The Euclidean distance between $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2} =\sqrt 2$. And the Euclidean distance between $(1,1,0)$ and $(2,2,0)$, which are two equivalent points embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, is $\sqrt{1^2+1^2+0^2} =\sqrt 2$ - the same distance. And the distance between equivalent points embedded in $\mathbb R^4$, $\mathbb R^5$ etc. is still $\sqrt 2$. The extra terms under the square root make no difference since they are all zero.

Comment: Hi, that is not exactly what I am talking about. as I stated "suppose 2 points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and \textbf{two other points} in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Say (0,0), (1,1) and (1,1,1), (2,2,2). Then $\sqrt{(1-0)^2 + (1-0)^2} = \sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{(2-1)^2+(2-1)^2+(2-1)^2} = \sqrt{3}$. Because, yes, they are different pairs of points. What I mean, are those two measures comparable? Are (0,0),(1,1) closer than (1,1,1),(2,2,2) in a meaningful way or the comparison is not valid. I am not talking about the projection of the same points in different spaces.
Thanks!

Comment: @nico_so $\sqrt 2 < \sqrt 3$ so, yes, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ are closer than $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ because $(0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$ are closer than $(1,1,1)$ and $(2,2,2)$ in $\mathbb R^3$.